# Best way to manage IIS configuration in IIS7

Tags: deployment, iis-7, configuration

We're moving our sites to use IIS7 and want some advice on the best way to manage the IIS settings.

We want to be able to put the settings into source control so they can be easily accessed by developers when they set up their local machine and be included in the package that gets deployed the the environments.

We have a branch for each team so we would prefer a text based format that can easily be merged when changes are forward integrated from the main branch.

We have six sites and would like the configuration for each site to live with the code for each site.

Our solution for IIS6 was to have metabase fragments checked into source control and automated through the WMI interface at deploy time. It doesn't seem like IIS7 has the same functionality.